# How to pass string parameters between C++ and C#?

Tags: c#, c++, string, interop, pinvoke

I have imported a C++ library in my C# project. I can get the answer of a C++ method that has no parameters. What I want to do is to send some string parameters to C++ and get the result of it.

In C++:

```
public String SomeMethod(String param1, String param2)
{
     //Some code
}
```

---

In C#:

```
[DllImport("Library Path")]
public static extern string SomeMethod(string param1, string param2);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean C++ Library means "C++ ATL Library"?

Comment: Use C++/CLI build a wrapper class

Answer (score 3):

For strings that are **input parameters** passed from C# to C++, you could just use `LPCWSTR` (i.e. `const wchar_t*`) at the interface on the C++ side, and marshal using the **`UnmanagedType.LPWstr`** option on the C# side.

But you must pay attention when you want to **return strings from C++ to C#**.
In fact, the string must somehow be allocated in C++, then the string pointer must be passed to C#. C# and the CLR must be able to properly *release* this string when it's no needed anymore, and this point can present issues. For example: C#/CLR should be able to release the string memory using the *same* allocator used by the C++ code to allocate the string.

This problem of using the same memory allocator for strings created in C++ and consumed in C# can be solved using **`BSTR`s**.
A `BSTR` is a COM string, that is allocated using the COM allocator, and can be freed using the *same* COM allocator. So, both the C++ and the C# side can share the same memory allocator for the string.

To return a `BSTR`, you can use the **`MarshalAs.UnmanagedTypeBStr`** option.

More details on string marshaling in C# can be found in [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx).

In **C++**:

```
//
// Note: Export using a pure C interface from C++ DLL.
// (You can use C++ *inside* the DLL boundaries.)
// __stdcall is a widely used calling convention for 
// C DLL functions (e.g. lots of Win32 APIs use it).
//
extern "C" BSTR __stdcall GetSomeString(void)
{
    //
    // Note: BSTRs are allocated using SysAllocString()
    // (...and freed using SysFreeString()).
    //
    // You could also use a convenient ATL RAII wrapper
    // (instead of using raw BSTRs inside C++ code), 
    // like CComBSTR.
    //
    return ::SysAllocString(L"Hello from C++!");
}
```

In **C#**:

```
[DllImport(@"YourDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
private static extern string GetSomeString();
```

If you choose to have `BSTR`s as the returned string, for *coherence* of the C++ function interface code, you may also want to use `BSTR`s as the *input* strings (even if that is not strictly necessary).

---

Another option you have is to request the **caller to provide a properly sized buffer** that the native C++ function will fill with the returned string. This is somewhat similar to what several Win32 APIs (like e.g. [`GetWindowText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) do.
As an example, [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext) you can find the corresponding P/Invoke for `GetWindwoText()`:

> ```
> [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
> static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
> ```

However, I think that returning a `BSTR` is nicer from a C# calling perspective (in fact, e.g. on the C# side you are not required to use a `StringBuilder` for the output string, etc.).

---

Last but not least, another option that you might be interested in is to build a tiny **C++/CLI bridging layer** to expose your native C++ code to C#, and marshal strings between native and managed using C++/CLI (and e.g. the `System::String` class).